# Why are only the column headers being formed in the latex document when I import the CSV file

Tags: tables, csv, csvsimple

This is a very basic version of what I am trying to do

```
\documentclass(article}
\usepackage(csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{example.csv}
\end{document}
```

I have also attached a small portion of the CSV file(let me know if that is what is causing the problem). ALso, it is in the form of code because the structure was being changed as text

```
RO,ST,Locid,City,Airport Name,S/L,Hub,CY 18 Enplanements,CY 17 Enplanements,% Change
SO,GA,ATL,Atlanta,Hartsfield Jackson Atlanta International,P,L,"51,865,797","50,251,964",3.2%
WP,CA,LAX,Los Angeles,Los Angeles International,P,L,"42,624,050","41,232,432",3.38%
GL,IL,ORD,Chicago,Chicago O'Hare International,P,L,"39,873,927","38,593,028",3.32%
SW,TX,DFW,Fort Worth,Dallas-Fort Worth International,P,L,"32,821,799","31,816,933",3.16%
NM,CO,DEN,Denver,Denver International,P,L,"31,362,941","29,809,097",5.21%
EA,NY,JFK,New York,John F Kennedy International,P,L,"30,620,769","29,533,154",3.68%
WP,CA,SFO,San Francisco International Airport,San Francisco International,P,L,"27,790,717","26,900,048",3.31%
NM,WA,SEA,Seattle,Seattle-Tacoma International,P,L,"24,024,908","22,639,124",6.12%
WP,NV,LAS,Las Vegas,McCarran International,P,L,"23,795,012","23,364,393",1.84%
SO,FL,MCO,Orlando,Orlando International,P,L,"23,202,480","21,565,448",7.59%
EA,NJ,EWR,Newark,Newark Liberty International,P,L,"22,797,602","21,571,198",5.69%
SO,NC,CLT,Charlotte,Charlotte/Douglas International,P,L,"22,281,949","22,011,251",1.23%
WP,AZ,PHX,Phoenix,Phoenix Sky Harbor International,P,L,"21,622,580","21,185,458",2.06%
SW,TX,IAH,Houston,George Bush Intercontinental/Houston,P,L,"21,157,398","19,603,731",7.93%
SO,FL,MIA,Miami,Miami International,P,L,"21,021,640","20,709,225",1.51%
NE,MA,BOS,Boston,General Edward Lawrence Logan International,P,L,"20,006,521","18,759,742",6.65%
GL,MN,MSP,Minneapolis,Minneapolis-St Paul International/Wold-Chamberlain,P,L,"18,361,942","18,409,704",-0.26%
SO,FL,FLL,Fort Lauderdale,Fort Lauderdale/Hollywood International,P,L,"17,612,331","15,817,043",11.35%
GL,MI,DTW,Detroit,Detroit Metropolitan Wayne County,P,L,"17,436,837","17,036,092",2.35%
EA,PA,PHL,Philadelphia,Philadelphia International,P,L,"15,292,670","14,271,243",7.16%
EA,NY,LGA,New York,Laguardia,P,L,"15,058,501","14,614,802",3.04%
EA,MD,BWI,Glen Burnie,Baltimore/Washington International Thurgood Marshall,P,L,"13,371,816","12,976,554",3.05%
NM,UT,SLC,Salt Lake City,Salt Lake City International,P,L,"12,226,730","11,615,954",5.26%
WP,CA,SAN,San Diego,San Diego International,P,L,"12,174,224","11,139,933",9.28%
EA,VA,IAD,Dulles,Washington Dulles International,P,L,"11,621,623","11,024,306",5.42%
EA,VA,DCA,Arlington,Ronald Reagan Washington National,P,L,"11,366,771","11,506,310",-1.21%
GL,IL,MDW,Chicago,Chicago Midway International,P,L,"10,678,018","10,912,074",-2.14%
```

[image: this is how the output looks]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. To start, replace `\documentclass(article} \usepackage(csvsimple}` with `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{csvsimple}`. (`{` instead of `(`.)

Comment: The first line of your csv file contains 9 columns while the second and following lines contain 10 columns. Also, replace the `"..."` yround the contents of column 8 and 9 with `{...}` as in `RO,ST,Locid,City,Airport Name,S/L,Hub,CY 18 Enplanements,CY 17 Enplanement,missing header
SO,GA,ATL,Atlanta,Hartsfield Jackson Atlanta International,P,L,{51,865,797},{50,251,964},3.2`.  If you do these changes your table will be included in your document. However it will be much wider than the textwidth and will therefore be only partly visible.